# Google Vision API for QR codes Not on Mobile Platform

Tags: node.js, qr-code, google-vision

I want to use Google's Vision API to extract the value of QR codes found on images that are sent by the user to a node server. Unfortunately, I could not find any solution or API from Google. Google has their own Mobile Vision API for Barcodes but as the name suggests, it is only on the mobile platform. Is there a way for me to do this? Does Google have their own API for this that I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan), not by google but does the work in any website, [example](https://schmich.github.io/instascan/).

use [jsQR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsqr) to read from image

Comment: I'm sorry but I may not have mentioned on the question that the data that is sent by the user to the server is not from a webcam, but from an image like a .jpg or .png file. Do you have any suggestions on this? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Will dive into this later.